# How can I write a program for how to use the maximum repeated observation value for repeated subject?

Tags: r

I need to rearrange the following data, for the same `ID` with only a maximum value of `A` and `B` variables

```
>j=read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
> j
  ID  A  B
1 22  9  8 
2 22 10  8 
3 23 20  9 
4 23 40  9 
5 23 50 10 
6 23 60  6
```

I wish to see the above data like the following:

```
j
  ID  A  B
1 22 10  8 
2 22 10  8 
3 23 60  10 
4 23 60  10 
5 23 60  10 
6 23 60  10
```

I tried to do using different methods but unfortunately, I am struggling with it

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, you can try grouping by `ID` and reassigning the maximum value of each column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(A = max(A),
         B = max(B))

# or

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, max))

#      ID     A     B
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1    22    10     8
# 2    22    10     8
# 3    23    60    10
# 4    23    60    10
# 5    23    60    10
# 6    23    60    10
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID  A  B
1 22  9  8 
2 22 10  8 
3 23 20  9 
4 23 40  9 
5 23 50 10 
6 23 60  6 ", h = T)
```